# Automate Network ACL on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, lambda, amazon-vpc

Is it possible to remove automatically the inbound rule at the Network ACL using Lambda functions?
I've searched to many blogs and documentation but none of them are legit. also i tried chatgpt but did not work.

source code if applicable.

hoping for your response thanks in advance
have a great day!!

Comment: We aren't here to write all your code for you. A request for all the source code to solve your problem isn't a valid question for this site. This site is for helping you solve specific programming problems, not for taking your requests and doing all the work for you. Please make some effort by looking at the AWS API documentation, and trying to do this yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible using the equivalent of the [delete-network-acl-entry](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2/client/delete_network_acl_entry.html) CLI operation in your function. For instance, in Python, you could use:

```py
response = client.delete_network_acl_entry(
    DryRun=True|False,
    Egress=True|False,
    NetworkAclId='string',
    RuleNumber=123
)
```

Comment: do you have a full syntax?

Comment: @EricDelosSantosBelgar What do you mean by that?